# Run a python or other language code inside Java

Tags: java, python, compilation, execution

We are building a grading system, and part of its job is to take input files, and from the given directory, our system will compile and run a (non-java) source code file written by the students. Then, the system will display the output from that run.

It is not limited to python, any other language that can meet the requirement is OK.

Is there is any method for providing for the location of the python code and the input file, and then run that code, returning the output file. If not, how can i achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) class. In particular, look at `Runtime.exec()`. It should enable you to execute external applications from within your Java program, as well as passing command line arguments, and specifying working directory.

Note that the `python` or any other program must have some well-defined way to get its input and write its output, such as passing filenames on the command line, or reading from `stdin`.